# Datepicker is causing IE9 to crash onSelect

Tags: jquery, datepicker, internet-explorer-9

I'm building out an app in html/jquery, and it determines a set of dates based on a user defined date.  So, I figured I'd use the handy jQuery datepicker.  Which works great - in Chrome, FF, IE8, and IE10.  But in IE 9 it crashes...  I'm running Vista 32-bit, and it's IE9.0.8112 if that's relevant.

Below is the relevant code... it never makes it to updateDates.

```
$('#finalPageDesc input').datepicker('destroy');
$('#finalPageDesc input').datepicker({
    onSelect:function(date){
        $('#finalPageDesc input').hide();
        var date=new Date(date);
        var m=formatMonth(date.getMonth());
        var d=date.getDate();
        var y=date.getFullYear();
        $('#finalPageDesc h3').html(m+' '+d+', '+y);
        $('#finalPageDesc h3').show();
        updateDates(m+' '+d+', '+y);
    }
});
```

Any thoughts??

Comment: whats in `formatMonths` and `updateDates`?

Comment: What exactly happens when it "crashes"?

Comment: I get a similar problem with the latest version of IE 11.  IE just crashes.  Error message is "Internet Explorer has stopped working"